# print a column and only display the 'Levels:' line

Tags: r

I want to inspect one particular column from my data frame in my code which has 4 different pattern. When I use `print(df[ ,column2])` then I get printed all rows and `Levels: -9999.99 Both EA ST`. And I only want to see `Levels: -9999.99 Both EA ST` in my console as a result.

Comment: Could probably just print(levels(df[,2]))

Comment: `cat("Levels:", levels(df[,2]))`